# How to make a macro button in a worksheet "saved as" from a file work but without reference to that old file?

Tags: excel, vba, button, self-reference

I built a macro in a file that can make a copy of a template worksheet and save as each of the newly generated worksheet as a new file under a designated folder in predefined file name.

The template worksheet has a macro that can sort the first column (yes, saved under that very worksheet) and show only the rows that have "Yes" in column A and a macro button, and the macro is assigned to the button.

In the new, saved file, the macro button is always linked with the macro in the old file, so every time I click the button, the macro opens the old file. In other words, the macro is reference the macro in the old file, not the macro in the active worksheet. If the old file is not open, the macro button will try to open that old file.

How can I make the macro button automatically linked with the macro in the worksheet?

The code is super simple, and I have made it working from current workbook and worksheet:

```
Sub SortRefresh()
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Yes"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found the reason.

The button added should be an ActiveX Controls button instead of Form Controls button. ActiveX Controls has its macro that is not "linked to" but embedded.

Right click the ActiveX Controls button add, then click "CommandButton Object" -> "Edit" , input 
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Yes"

After the new file has been saved, clicking on the ActiveX Controls Button will not result in opening up the old file.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are copying workbook with the below code

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "E:\XXXX.XLSM"
```

Please try to right click on the button and check with assign Macro, You check whether it is referencing to sub of the copied workbook

Comment: Yes, the new file is saved a macro enabled excel file. The macro, which is actually the one in the old file, can run in the new file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to export the module with the code to the new workbook:

```
Dim strFolder As String, strTempFile As String
strFolder = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Path
strFolder = strFolder & "\"
strTempFile = strFolder & "~tmpexport.bas"
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Export strTempFile
Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Import strTempFile
Kill strTempFile
```

Comment: I tried, but the macro button in the new file still refer to the macro Module1 in the old file.